# How to evaluate $\lim_{n \to \infty}{\frac{a_1 \cdot a_2\cdot a_3 \ldots a_{n}}{a_{n+1}}}$, given $a_{n+1} = a_{n}^{2} -1,a_1 = \sqrt{5}$?

Tags: limits, recurrence-relations

Let $a_{n+1} = a_{n}^{2} -1,a_1 = \sqrt{5}.$  How would one evaluate $$\lim_{n \to \infty}{\frac{a_1 \cdot a_2\cdot a_3 \ldots a_{n}}{a_{n+1}}}?$$

**Added**: Someone else asked me this question today, but unfortunately I don't know how to start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Offset by one, this is a [known sequence](http://oeis.org/search?q=4%2C15%2C224%2C50175&language=english&go=Search).  Without the offset, we have $$a_{n}=\left\lceil c^{2^n}\right\rceil$$
(for $n\ge 2$) where $c$ is some constant between 1 and 2.

The fraction in the limit is approximated by $$\frac{\sqrt{5}c^{2^1}c^{2^2}\cdots c^{2^n}}{c^{2^{n+1}}}=\frac{\sqrt{5}c^{2^{n+1}-2}}{c^{2^{n+1}}}=\frac{\sqrt{5}}{c^2}$$

Comment: Tons of thanks for your lucid answer.

Comment: You can not have a equal sign here, at best you may say $\lim_{n\to \infty} \ln \frac{a_1a_2\cdots a_{n-1}}{a_n}=1$.

Comment: My pleasure, hope this helps.

Comment: @MaMing, the three fractions are indeed equal, and all of them are approximations for the fraction in the limit (which has lots of ceilings).  Hence the true limit is $\ge\frac{\sqrt{5}}{c^2}$.

Comment: @vadim123 You cannot drop the ceilings.

Comment: @vadim123 Using $a_n< c^{2^n}+1$, one may show that the limit exist.